# How can I properly catch errors of a Node js script in Python using Naked?

Tags: python, node.js, django, amp-html

I am using Naked library of Python mentioned [here](http://sweetme.at/2014/02/17/a-simple-approach-to-execute-a-node.js-script-from-python/) for executing a Nodejs script which is also available [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amphtml-validator) too. The point is, whenever I run my python script(exactly taken from the above link) through the terminal I can able to see the output of the nodejs script. I included this python script into my Django server and running it whenever an API call is made.

I couldn't able to catch the errors properly when the validation of the page fails. It always returns 'success'. I feel this is because Nodejs is asynchronous. If it is so, how can I make the function 'amphtmlValidator.getInstance().then(function(validator)' mentioned in the npm website to synchronous? I am really very much new to Nodejs.

Actually I just need to validate AMP pages from python script in Django and the only way I found is calling the node script through python. Everything is ok, but I couldn't catch the errors properly.
Please help.

Comment: Your javascript is indeed asynchronous (`.then(function()...)`) but returns `True` immediately to your python script. What happens in the `then()` clause happens asynchronously, and there's no way to callback into python. To my knowledge what you want is not possible. You would have to re-write the amphtmlvalidator code to be synchronous. Maybe you're better off using a 3rd party API service to check your documents directly from python?

Comment: Yes, all I need to do is validate the AMP pages (HTML code) from python and as amphtml validator is only available to Node, I am thinking something like to invoke the nodejs script from python. This works perfectly fine on the console, but when running through the server the node script is giving me true immediately as you said. I am open to any other library to validate the AMP pages.

Comment: Ok clear now. Sorry I don’t have a suggestion here.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by writing the "getInstance()" code into an async function and then added a sleep of 2 seconds which ensures that all the data is written into the console. I am adding manually a keyword "ERROR" if any errors are raised in the node script else I am adding "PASS".

Whenever I execute this script using Python, I will check for the keywords. I knew that this answer is not good, but I could able to manage the things working.
Here is what I have done:

**NODE Script:**

```
    function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms)
  })
}

// async function that accepts a html file content and validates
async function validation(file) {
  //console.log(file);
  amphtmlValidator.getInstance().then(
    function(validator) {
      var result = validator.validateString(file);
      if (result.status === 'PASS') {
        console.log("PASS")
      } else {
        for (var ii = 0; ii < result.errors.length; ii++) {
          var error = result.errors[ii];
          var msg = 'ERROR : ' + 'line ' + error.line + ', col ' + error.col + ': ' + error.message;
          console.log(msg);
        }
      }
    });
  await sleep(2000);
}
```

**Python:**

```
response = muterun_js("validate.js", args)

if response:
  if "ERROR" in response.stdout.decode():
      print("validation failed")
  elif "PASS" in response.stdout.decode():
      print("success")
```